# setting line spacing locally using \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}

Tags: line-spacing, setspace

I'd like to change spacing locally (without packages such as "setspace").
My preamble:

```
    \documentclass[11pt]{book} %[makeidx,bezier,theorem, ukrain]
    \textheight=172mm
    \textwidth=112mm
    \usepackage{makeidx}
    \makeindex
    %\nofiles
    \usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
    \usepackage[cp1251]{inputenc}

    \usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,calc} 
    \usepackage{indentfirst}
    \usepackage{amsmath,multicol}
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{amsthm}
    \usepackage{amscd}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage[mathscr]{eucal}
    \usepackage[dvips]{color} %%% ????

    \usepackage{layout}
    \usepackage{floatflt}
    \usepackage{nccsect} 
    \usepackage{calc}
    \usepackage{here}
    \usepackage[normalem]{ulem}   %%%%% ДЛЯ КОЛОНТИТ. 

    \includeonly{
    pr,
    ch0,
    ch1,
    ch2,
    ch3,
    ch4,
    ch5
    }
    \newtheorem{ex}{\hspace*{\parindent}Пример}[section]

    \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{0.8} %%%% !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

    \usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[LE]{\emph\textit{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}}
    \fancyhead[RO]{\emph\textit{\nouppercase{\rightmark} \hfill \thepage}}
    \lfoot{}
    \rfoot{}
```

I'm trying to stretch a block of a page so that it is stretched 
nicely to fill the page completely.

```
    %%%% ==== a block of ch4.tex =======
    \begin{ex} $\!\!$ {\bf (``шахматный город'').}
    Рассмотрим   прямоугольную сетку квадратов --- ``шахматный город'',
    состоящий из $m\times n$  квадратных кварталов, разделенных $n-1$
    ``горизонтальными'' и $m-1$ ``вертикальными'' улицами $($см. рис. $\ref{net})$.
    Сколько существует на этой сетке различных кратчайших путей, ведущих из
    левого нижнего  угла $($точки  $(0,0)$$)$ в правый верхний угол $($точку
    $(m,n)$$)$?
    \end{ex}

    \begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics{PICS/Anya/4_3_1.eps}
    \caption{\label{net} ``Шахматный город'' }
    \end{figure}

    %%%% ET 
    \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.9} 
    %%%% ==TRYING TO CHANGE LINE SPACING ==
    Р\,е\,ш\,е\,н\,и\,е.
    Обозначим  буквой ``Г''  горизонтальный
    отрезок пути, буквой ``В'' --- вертикальный. Каждый  
    кратчайший путь из $(0,0)$ в $(m,n)$ состоит из $n$ 
    вертикальных отрезков и $m$ горизонтальных. Он полностью 
    задается LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM  .....................  



    \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{0.8} %%% STANDARD linestretch 
    \newpage
```

But the piece between `\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.9}`  and 
`\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{0.8}` refuses to stretch! What should I do?

I'd prefer to solve the problem without extra packages. But if this is hard, 
does the code
       `\usepackage{setspace}\setstretch{<factor>}`
give the same factor as 
    `\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{<factor>}`
? I.e., is `\setstretch{1.2}` equivalent to  1.2 factor of `\baselinestretch`?

Comment: Welcome! Why do you want to avoid `setspace`? It's the recommended way to do this.

Comment: From the package: `\newcommand{\setstretch}[1]{%
  \def\baselinestretch{#1}%
  \@currsize
}`, so you can see that `\setstretch` passes the argument straight through to redefine `\baselinestretch`.

Comment: Please provide code which people can compile to reproduce the problem. Right now, nobody but you can see what you're seeing as we've just got a fragment and no way to complete it.

Answer (score 5):

You need a font change/selection to reset the baselineskip:

```
\documentclass{article}


\begin{document}
some text\\ some text

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.9} 
some text\\ some text %here no change

\selectfont %now it works
some text\\ some text


\end{document}
```

[image]