# Single-spaced comments in changes package with double-spaced document

Tags: spacing, changes

I'm using the `changes` package for comments. Is it possible to get the comments to be single-spaced, even if the document itself is double-spaced?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{changes}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\linespread{2}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-1][1-3]\comment{I would like this comment to be single-spaced.} \lipsum[1-1][4-6]

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: BTW, `\comment` is also used by other packages (defined differently).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quite likely you want all of your margin notes to be single spaced.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{changes,etoolbox}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\preto\@marginparreset{\linespread{1}}
\makeatother

\linespread{2}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-1][1-3]\comment{I would like this comment to be single-spaced.}
\lipsum[1-1][4-6]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Explanation: `\@marginparreset` is the hook that the LaTeX kernel provides for doing initializations before starting to typeset a margin paragraph (internally used by the `changes` package).

Comment: Simple and easy. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Using [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/436480/121799) I tried

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{changes}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\linespread{2}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-1][1-3]\renewcommand*{\baselinestretch}{1}\comment{\selectfont  
I would like this comment to be single-spaced.} 
\lipsum[1-1][4-6]

\end{document}
```

[image]

which seems to work. If you decide this is the way to go, then obviously one may make it more automatic and safer by patching this into `\comment`. You could just look up its definition from `changes.sty` and redefine it as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{changes}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\linespread{2}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\comment}[2][\@empty]{%
\edef\oldbaselinestretch{\baselinestretch}%
\typeout{\oldbaselinestretch}%
\renewcommand*{\baselinestretch}{1}%
\setkeys{Changes@comment}{#1}%
\Changes@output%
{comment}%
{\Changes@comment@id}%
{}%
{}%
{\selectfont #2}%
{\changescommentname}%
{\selectfont #2}%
\renewcommand*{\baselinestretch}{\oldbaselinestretch}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-1][1-3]\comment{I would like this comment to be single-spaced.} 
\lipsum[1-1][4-6]

\selectfont
\lipsum[1-1]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Clever! I was trying to fix `\baselineskip`, which has to be done before the paragraph starts. I found only one `\marginpar` in the changes source, but patching it didn't do anything.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Thanks! All I did was to look up Ulrike's answer and use the information there.